# Eclipse wrong preference on String.valueOf()?

Tags: eclipse

When I write `String.valueOf` the first suggestion I get from Eclipse is `copyValueOf`, which is very annoying for development.

Does anybody have an idea what to do? I couldn't find anything in the preferences.

In the Eclipse Preferences under Editor > Content Assist then Sorting and Filtering -> Sort proposals are set to "by relevance" and not "alphabetically". So that can't be the issue.

Eclipse version: Neon.1a Release (4.6.1)
Build id: 20161007-1200

[image]

Comment: In the Eclipse Preferences under Editor > Content Assist then Sorting and Filtering -> Sort proposals are set to "by relevance" and not "alphabetically". So that can't be the issue.

Comment: Exactly where is your text cursor in this image? After the 'f'?

Comment: so I think that you can include what you commented on your question. what version of eclipse you are using ? @PrestigeDev

Comment: @nitind yes, after the 'f'. The screenshot software seems to hide the cursor.

Comment: @LKTN.25 
Version: Neon.1a Release (4.6.1)
Build id: 20161007-1200

Comment: What's written in the lower right corner of this pop-up?

Comment: @nitind "Press Ctrl+Space to show Template Proposals" (There are Java, Scout and SWT Proposals. When pressing a few times, the order willl correctify itself in order that valueOf is the first shown proposal. but on rewrite of "String." --> copyValueOf is the first shown method again ...

Comment: Did you ever figure out a fix for this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Reinstalled eclipse and the problem never occured since.